# How to set a width of the background (HTML and CSS)

Tags: html, css

So I want to make the gradient in the background of my webpage to not keep going and have a width. I am not sure how to do this and I tried in the css but it didn't work.

[image: My HTML]

[image: My Css]

I'm sorry that my css it is a bit blurry but I had to fit it in one screenshot.

Comment: post your code in order to check

Comment: @Dhruv - Please, do not post links to images of code. Just post the code itself! It's quicker, consumes less bandwidth and makes for a far more usable post - one that's still available if the external site goes down.

Comment: @enhzflep- I tried, but it said my code was not formatted properly.

Comment: @Dhruv, to properly format, copy and paste your code, highlight it, and click `Ctrl - K`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be the code.

```
body { /*or whatever element*/
    background-size:#px #px; /*replace size for #'s*/
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a CSS property called background-size. Here is more information about it http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp. Setting the width of the body won't work you have to set the background size.